# How to get an equivalent of WeightedData in Mathematica 8?

Tags: probability-or-statistics, data

Is there an equivalent command of `WeightedData` (new in version 9) in Mathematica 8 or I have to define it by myself? I haven't found anything in the site or googleing it... If there is not such command do you have some suggestions for defining it?

Comment: In order to create your own `WeightedData` you need to define it separately for every function that is supposed to accept it, I think. E.g. `Unprotect[Mean]; Mean[WeightedData[data_,weight_]]:= data.weight/Total[w];`. You should now be to do this: `obj = WeightedData[data,weights]; Mean[obj]`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It might be useful to consider TagSet here, to provide a new rule to Mean when it encounters your new data object:

```
weightedData/:Mean[data_weightedData] :=Mean[List@@data[[1]]]
```

You can style your object so it looks the same as the M9 object:

```
Format[weightedData[data_]]:=Panel["weightedData[" <> ToString[Length[data]] <> "]"];
```

Now a function that builds your data object, there should be more error checking than currently implemented and MapThread was the first thing I thought of:

```
weightedData[data_, weights_] /; Length[data] == Length[weights]:= Module[{weighted},
weighted = MapThread[#1/#2 &,
{data1,weights}];
weightedData[weighted]]
```

Make some data and test it:

```
In[10]:=data1={1,2,3};
weights={4,5,6};
test1=weightedData[data1,weights];
Mean[test1]
Out[10]:=23/60
```

To make other functions play nice just use TagSet again

```
weightedData /: ListLinePlot[data_weightedData]:=ListLinePlot[List @@ data[[1]]];
ListLinePlot[test1]
```

[image]